# filter every single value using onChangeText from nested array in react-native

Tags: javascript, angularjs, react-native

I am having an array with nested childs in it , the children can be one or upto n values , **I am trying to implement local filter** inside my component. **When ever user type anything in textInput** the **application will start showing Suggestions to user based on word he/she typed** And the suggestion will come from my pre-defined array.

Here is my code which i am using right now :-

```
export function onSearch(categoryList, searchText) {
    var searchList = [];
    return function(dispatch) {
       categoryList.map((item, i) => {
           if (item.title.includes(searchText)) {
             searchList.push(item);
           }
       });
       dispatch({
         type: types.Search_Success,
         payload: searchList
       });
    };
}
```

**AS in the above method you can see that code will filter value upto parent value only so i tried to add code by putting condition like** :-

```
if(item.children.length>0){
    item.children.map((item, i) => {
        if (item.title.includes(searchText)) {
            searchList.push(item);
        }
    });
}
```

but the **Problem is i can have many children so i can not put conditions like this inside code**

Here is what my array looks like :-

```
[{
    "id": "38",
    "title": "What's New",
    "url": "what-is-new"
}, {
    "id": "20",
    "title": "Women",
    "url": "women",
    "children": [{
        "id": "21",
        "title": "Tops",
        "url": "tops-women",
        "children": [{
            "id": "23",
            "title": "Jackets",
            "url": "jackets-women"
        }, {
            "id": "24",
            "title": "Hoodies & Sweatshirts",
            "url": "hoodies-and-sweatshirts-women"
        }, {
            "id": "25",
            "title": "Tees",
            "url": "tees-women"
        }, {
            "id": "26",
            "title": "Bras & Tanks",
            "url": "tanks-women"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "22",
        "title": "Bottoms",
        "url": "bottoms-women",
        "children": [{
            "id": "27",
            "title": "Pants",
            "url": "pants-women"
        }, {
            "id": "28",
            "title": "Shorts",
            "url": "shorts-women"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": "11",
    "title": "Men",
    "url": "men",
    "children": [{
        "id": "12",
        "title": "Tops",
        "url": "tops-men",
        "children": [{
            "id": "14",
            "title": "Jackets",
            "url": "jackets-men"
        }, {
            "id": "15",
            "title": "Hoodies & Sweatshirts",
            "url": "hoodies-and-sweatshirts-men"
        }, {
            "id": "16",
            "title": "Tees",
            "url": "tees-men"
        }, {
            "id": "17",
            "title": "Tanks",
            "url": "tanks-men"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "13",
        "title": "Bottoms",
        "url": "bottoms-men",
        "children": [{
            "id": "18",
            "title": "Pants",
            "url": "pants-men"
        }, {
            "id": "19",
            "title": "Shorts",
            "url": "shorts-men"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

No what i want is when i type "m" it should gives me all the titles who contains "m" inside it.

Please let me know if i am not much clear with my question.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to write a recursive function that will solve your problem, like the following:

```
export const onSearch = (categoryList, searchText) => {
  return dispatch => {
    const suggestions = []

    const addToSuggestions = item => {
      if (item.title.includes(searchText)) {
        suggestions.push(item)
      }
      if (item.children) {
        item.children.forEach(addToSuggestions)
      }
    }

    categoryList.forEach(addToSuggestions)

    dispatch({
      type: types.Search_Success,
      payload: suggestions
    })
  }
}
```